# Load a component while consuming angular library

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-library

let's say I have an angular library called my-lib. 
This library is a dialog which consist of header, content and a footer.
My case is I want to consume this library and I want to load any component in the content section of the library.

Let's say, I want to use it like this:

```
<my-lib [title]="_title">
  <any-component></any-component>
</my-lib>
```

Here, the any-component will be loaded in content section of the dialog.
How can I achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: checkout https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: @user733421 Let me check! Thanks for the link :)